List all the shared tables that don't have a row access policy
We want to make sure that any/all tables that are shared also have the Row Access Policy assigned to them. Is there a way to list which tables are being shared?
(from https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/1bz939f/list_the_tables_in_a_database_that_are_being/)

The basics:

With show shares you can find all the created shares on an account (with the role accountadmin or one with enough permissions)
Then you need to iterate over each share to find all the tables shared.
Then you can go find if any of those tables are not listed on snowflake.account_usage.policy_references.

The challenge here is that you can't directly use the results of show on subsequent queries without a little bit of data manipulation.
For convenience I created a Snowflake Python stored procedure that goes over all the steps:
use role accountadmin;

-- anonymous procedure, will call() at the end
with x as procedure()
returns table()
language python
runtime_version='3.11'
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
handler='run'
as $$

from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def run(session):
    # list all the shares
    shares = session.sql('show shares').filter(col('"kind"')=='OUTBOUND')

    table_names = set()
    # for each share, find the table names
    for share in shares.to_local_iterator():
        shared_objects = session.sql('desc share identifier(:1)', (share['name'],)).collect()
        table_names.update([x['name'] for x in shared_objects if x['kind']=='TABLE'])
        
    # find which of these table names don't have a ROW_ACCESS_POLICY on snowflake.account_usage.policy_references
    return session.sql('''
        with entities_with_row_access_policies as (
            select ref_database_name || '.' || ref_schema_name || '.' || ref_entity_name full_name
            from snowflake.account_usage.policy_references
            where policy_kind = 'ROW_ACCESS_POLICY'
        )
    
        select value table_name
        from table(split_to_table(:1, ','))
        where table_name not in (
            select full_name 
            from entities_with_row_access_policies
        )
    ''', (','.join(table_names), ))
$$
call x();


